Solution of Heat Equation at Upper Half-Plane

I am doing the following problem from Evans' book, Partial Differential Equations. I try to use the hint so I define $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-g(t)$ for $x>0$, and $v(x,t)=g(t)-u(-x,t)$ for $x<0$. Now we have
\begin{aligned}
v_t-v_{xx}&=-g'(t), &\quad x,t>0\\
v_t-v_{xx}&=g'(t),&\quad x<0,t>0\\
v&=0,&\quad x=0.
\end{aligned}
If I use the formula of solution for heat equation then I am done. But the formula is true if we have $v_t-v_{xx}=f$ then $f$ is continuous and has compact support, but for this I know nothing about $g$. How do I resolve this?

For the initial condition of $v$, we substitute $v(x,0) = u(x,0) - g(0) = 0$ for $x >0$; $v(x,0) = g(0) - u(-x,0) = 0$ for $x < 0$, and $v(0,0) = \pm(u(0,0) - g(0)) = 0$ and so we have a zero initial condition for $v$. This is trivially continuous with compact support

@Andrew ah, I meant in the book for non-homogeneous heat equation, the function in the differential equation $v_t-v_{xx}=f$ must satisfy that $f \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty))$
